# Как устранить ошибку при установке Visual Studio 2022 IDE?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-10

### Вначале такая штука загрузка не идет потом вылезает ошибка
[image: Visual Studio Installer]

**Текст ошибки**

> Не удалось скачать установочные файлы.
> проверти подключение к интернету и повторите попытку.

[image: TEXT ERROR]

> **Интернет работает с ним всё в порядке**

**Пытался пробовать Изоляция ключей CNG**

> Win+R ➜ services.msc ➜ Изоляция ключей CNG ➜ Поменять тип запуска на «Вручную», запустить её ➜ Запустить установщик Visual Studio ➜ Радоваться
>
> Но Это не помогло

[image: Изоляция ключей CNG]

Comment: vpn bro :) мне помог только vpn

Comment: не подскажешь какой побыстрее и бесплатный

Comment: я использовал первый попавшийся который на пк. Скачал vs, удалил vpn, забыл.

Comment: и да, там главное сервер выбирай относительно своего места положения. И будет тебе скорость, у меня сильно не резалась, я ближе к западу, выбирал Нидерланды вроде, скорость была точно такая же(почти) как заявлял провайдер.